# Is there a way to import JSON template exports via an API?

Tags: docusignapi

We would like to be able to import templates that were downloaded from other unconnected DocuSign accounts. Preferably using node.js. I have not been able to find any documentation that specifically says what is able to be done around this.

If this is not possible, is it possible from the UI? It seems like it was supported but might not be anymore.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is make a

```
POST ..restapi/v2.1/accounts/>AccountID>/templates
```

And provide the JSON of the template in the body of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. As Inbar pointed out, the best course of action here maybe to do a POST call to ..restapi/v2.1/accounts/>AccountID>/templates

and get the definition of each template definition you need using

GET ..restapi/v2.1/accounts/>AccountID>/templates/{{templateId}}

Then you can create the new templates in your account using the definition you just retrieved.